# How to make more than one label copy to clipboard with a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, copy, copy-paste

I set up a button called "copyButton". Now I have 7 different labels displaying text. I was wondering if there is a way to set it up so I can copy all the labels at once and past them so they are all together. My labels are named Label1, Label2, and so on until Label7. If they display 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, all seperately. With clicking the copy button it should be able to be pasted as 1234567. I am not sure if this can be done, I may just have to move them all to a text box or into one label.

Comment: just have a method that concatenates all of the labels' text, and then add that to the clipboard

Comment: How would I do this? I am kind of new to C# and am still learning a lot if you couldnt tell haha :p

Comment: Make a new method in the form that returns a string. It would look something like `private string ConcatenateLabels() { return Label1.Text + Label2.Text + Label3.Text ...etc }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this.

```
var textCopy = Labe1.Text + Label2.Text; // upto 7
Clipboard.SetText(textCopy);
```

and if you want a general solution you can do this..
this will copy all text of Labels inside a form.
and will set it to clipboard. later on you can paste.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string textToCopy = "";
            foreach (var control in this.Controls) {
                var label =  control as Label;
                if (label !=null) {
                      //by this way will show in assending order
                      textToCopy = label.Text + textToCopy;
                }

            }

            Clipboard.SetText(textToCopy);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Clipboard.SetText(Label1.Content+ Label2.Content+ Label3.Content+ Label4.Content+ Label5.Content+ Label6.Content+ Label7.Content)
```

This is for WPF, if you are using Windows Form then you replace Content with Text.